# diagnosing an incompatibility between pythontex and a siam .cls file

Tags: document-classes, pythontex

I'm using pythontex within a documentclass provided by SIAM (see http://www.siam.org/meetings/ns14/siam-wns-article.cls - less than 100 lines for the 2014 version which has the same problem as the 2018 version).

When I compile

```
\documentclass{siam-wns-article}
\usepackage{pythontex}


\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

I get an error:

> \c@listing=\count122
>
> ./tmp.tex:5: You can't use `\relax' after \the.
>
> \c@float@type

The output of my actual example is fine.  But the error persists and the organizers of the conference have said they will want original tex files for the final proceedings.  So I'd like to make sure that I can tell them what needs to be fixed in the documentclass.  But I haven't been able to figure it out.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The problem is because your class file loads the `listings` package which, is [incompatible with `pythontex`](https://github.com/gpoore/pythontex/issues/61).

Comment: See https://github.com/axelsommerfeldt/caption/issues/5

Comment: This has been fixed in `newfloat`, see https://github.com/axelsommerfeldt/caption/commit/309be570ec353b18dec4b882e99c287ed70e4a89

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is as described in https://github.com/gpoore/pythontex/issues/61 and https://github.com/axelsommerfeldt/caption/issues/5

Workaround: use a different name for the PythonTeX floats (independently if you use them or not).

```
\documentclass{siam-wns-article}
\usepackage{pythontex}

\setpythontexlistingenv{pylisting}

\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

Explanation of the issue. The `newfloat` package tests for `\c@float@type` being defined with `\ifdefined` and this is wrong: it should use `\@ifundefined`. The problem arises when `listings` is loaded, because this package *does* use `\@ifundefined{c@float@type}`, which leaves `\c@float@type` equivalent to `\relax` and then `\ifdefined\c@float@type` returns true. The SIAM class you're using loads `listings`.

A bug in `newfloat`.

Comment: Hi @egreg, if the bug is in `newfloat`, shouldn't it be reported (and fixed) there?

Comment: @FaheemMitha Indeed, I filed an issue report at https://github.com/axelsommerfeldt/caption/issues/5

Comment: Oh, looks like `newfloat` is contained in the `caption` package. Thanks for the bug report.

Comment: Fixed in `newfloat`, see https://github.com/axelsommerfeldt/caption/commit/309be570ec353b18dec4b882e99c287ed70e4a89

Answer (score 4):

the error message suggests a counter `float@type` is not defined

```
grep 'newcounter.*float@type' /usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/*/*.*
```

turns up `float.sty` and a possible fix is therefore

```
\documentclass{siam-wns-article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{pythontex}


\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

runs without error.

I note however that pythontex loads newfloat so this is perhaps not the best fix as you probably don't really want float and newfloat both loaded and the other answer points to a clue and then a bit of tracing reveals that this is the 
common problem of the latex test `\@ifundefined{c@float@typ}` having a side  effect of defining `\c@float@type` to be `\relax` due to a curious feature of the `\csname` primitive.

As it happens the next release of latex will probably have code to avoid this issue but meanwhile you can set `\c@float@type` back to being undefined

```
\documentclass{siam-wns-article}

\AtBeginDocument{%
\expandafter\ifx\csname c@float@type\endcsname\relax
\expandafter\let\csname c@float@type\endcsname\undefined
\fi
}
\usepackage{pythontex}



\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative to David's answer, if you can modify the class file.

The problem seems to come from an [incompatibility between `pythontex` and `listings`](https://github.com/gpoore/pythontex/issues/61) (the latter, which is loaded by your class file).

As noted in one of the comments from the GitHub page of the issue, loading `pythontex` before `listings` solves the issue (or not loading listings at all:).

So put `pythontex` before `listings` and you're good to go.

Comment: oh that points to a better fix thanks +1 I'll update my answer